# Transição em fade entre sessões de um site com conteúdos diferentes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Olá,

Preciso fazer um efeito de transição da como desse site: http://brewlife.com/

Com a rolagem o conteúdo de uma sessão vai sumindo em fade e vai aparecendo um novo conteúdo, da sessão seguinte, se sobrepondo a anterior.

Comment: Uma coisa que ajudaria a obter uma resposta seria [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar o código até onde você chegou, e ser mais específica na dificuldade que está tendo. Veja aqui algumas dicas para deixar a questão mais contextualizada para o site: [Ask].

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) + [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). Basta adicionar a classe com o efeito que deseja 
junto com a classe wow. No site ele explica direitinho como você instala o plugin, mas o HTML ficaria basicamente assim:

```
<div class="fadeInUp wow"> ... </div> <!-- efeito usado na parte laranja, por exemplo, já na parte da equipe, utilizaram um fadeInLeft na div dos membros -->
```

Você conseguirá um efeito semelhante.

Espero ter ajudado.